# Radical w/ Variables Addition Simplification

Tags: radicals

I am working through some calculus problems and I am running into some trouble with simplifying a radical. I have a feeling there is an obvious rule for something like this that is simply eluding me at the moment, but here it is:

$${(x-1)}^{5/3} +\frac{5}{3}(x+2)(x-1)^{2/3}$$

How does this simplify to:

$$\frac{1}{3}(x-1)^{2/3}(8x+7) $$

Comment: Hint: $\;5/3=1+2/3\,$ so $\,(x-1)^{5/3}=(x-1)\cdot(x-1)^{2/3}\,$.

Comment: Thanks dxiv. "Oh, duh" moment.  Should I delete this question?